# What similarity metric should be used to classify these sequences?

Tags: algorithm, numpy, scipy, pattern-matching, classification

I have 96 sequences of 48 floating point numbers. There are three distinct groupings (of unknown size). Initially, I do not know which sequence belongs to which group. My aim is to create an algorithm to find this. This is best shown pictorially (see below - the magnitude of the floats represented on a gray scale):

[image]

I aim to go from the unsorted image on the left to the image on the right.

My thoughts are to do some form of analysis on the sequences  and group the closest matching. The analysis might be:

- A. Finding the locations of peaks and troughs
- B. Some form
  frequency/other domain analysis

I can imagine how to do option A. However I'm sketchy on option B and am sure that I'm unaware of several methods.

My questions are high level:

1. Can anyone recommend a category of algorithms that I could use to do this?
2. Can anyone recommend a procedure or starting point for developing such an algorithm (book chapter recommendations welcome)?

I'd also be happy with recommendations for book chapters etc. I usually use Numpy/Scipy - hence the tags, but this question is not really language specific.

Comment: I don't understand what defines the distance (similarity metric?) between the sequences. Still, this seems to fall into the "classification" class of problems.

Comment: @RafałDowgird - It's a good way of rephrasing the question, "What similarity metric could be used to classify these sequences?"  It looks like the peaks and troughs line up differently in the 3 groups - so the location of these could be the similarity metric. But I have a feeling there might be a better way (hence the question).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the peaks and troughs are perfectly aligned and only differ in depth. I'd try to:

- Linearly normalize sequences, so that both their averages and variances are aligned, i.e. both [1,0,1,0] and [5,-5,5,-5] normalize to [1,-1,1,-1].
- Then calculate sum of squares of differences on the sequences and treat it as the distance.

Obviously it's just a starting point. This probably won't work out of the box, so look at misclassifications to check what causes them and how to work around that.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought (don't have time to write a complete answer):

1. it seems that members within a group mainly differ by some scaling, so first do some sort of 'normalization', as suggested by Rafal.
2. After the normalization, all members within a group will be vectors that roughly point in the same direction in N-dimensional space. You could then divide them into groups is using some [clustering algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering), for example using the [kmeans](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans.html) function.